# Code for input option sort by asc

Tags: php, sorting

I have code this:

```
...............    
else
if($fieldname_default == "Author"){
echo "<label class='control-label' for='".$fieldname_default."'>".$fieldname."</label>
<div class='controls'>
<select name='data[".$fieldname_default."]' id='".$fieldname_default."'>";
$get_categories_sql = mysql_query("select * from authors");
while($get_categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_categories_sql))
{ 
echo "<option value='".$get_categories['Author_Name']."'>".$get_categories['Author_Name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>                         
</div></div>";
}
....................
```

where I add code for input option sort by ACS or DESC?
Thank for anyone who will answered.

Comment: in the query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: see my suggestion answer below @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make it easier you can alter your query by AuthorName for example :

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM authors ORDER BY AuthorName ASC")
```

Comment: Nin-ya, thank for your quick answer. My question id resolved.